# Rhino Mock throws an exception when raising an event

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

Is it possible to simulate an event using Rhino Mocks framework without getting the exception below?

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Rhino.Mocks.dll - Can't create mocks of sealed classes

```
    public interface IWithEvent
    {
        event EventHandler RaiseMeWithoutExceptionPlease;
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class MockedEvents
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void EventsTest()
        {
            IWithEvent withEvent = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWithEvent>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                // 500 exceptions thrown 
                withEvent.Raise(we => we.RaiseMeWithoutExceptionPlease += null, withEvent, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, paste the code that raises this exception...