# How to Stub a property without getting 3 exceptions?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

RhinoMocks throws 3 exception when stubbing a simple readonly property. How to do it without getting the exceptions.

```
public class ThirdPartyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ThirdPartyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public interface IWithProperty
{
    ThirdPartyClass MyReadonlyProperty { get; }
}

[TestClass]
public class MockedProperty
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void PropertyTest()
    {
        IWithProperty withProperty = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWithProperty>();

        // 3 exceptions thrown
        withProperty.Stub(wp => wp.MyReadonlyProperty).Return(new ThirdPartyClass("Mocked"));
    }
}
```

That throws 3 following exception in 1 line:

> System.MissingMethodException occurred   Message=Constructor on type
>   'Castle.Proxies.ThirdPartyClassProxyc32aba1028c144bb844d190d92ad191a'
>   not found.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes)   InnerException:
>
> System.MissingMethodException occurred   Message=Constructor on type
>   'Castle.Proxies.ThirdPartyClassProxyc32aba1028c144bb844d190d92ad191a'
>   not found.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes)   InnerException:
>
> System.ArgumentException occurred   Message=Can not instantiate proxy
>   of class: Test.ThirdPartyClass. Could not find
>   a parameterless constructor. Parameter name: constructorArguments
>   Source=Rhino.Mocks   ParamName=constructorArguments   StackTrace:
>          at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy,
>   ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments,
>   IInterceptor[] interceptors)   InnerException:

Comment: just curious, what happens if you add a default (parameterless) constructor?

Comment: It doesn't throw exceptions if the property type has got a parameterless constructor. However, as it's a class coming from a third party library I can't add that constructor.

Comment: Quite strange... It works as expected for me for Rhino.Mock 3.6. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.6.0.0 as well. It manages to stub the property but if you have a look at the trace or enable thrown CLR exceptions in VS (Ctrl+D, E) you'll see them. The same happens when you raise an event (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648994/rhino-mock-throws-an-exception-when-raising-an-event). It's annoying because it floods you with exceptions and hides the important ones. The rule of thumb is exceptions should not be used to control the flow of your program and this seems to happen inside RhinoMocks.